# can I add a signature to mail in Elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-mail

How can I add my signature to mail?
I can't find any resource to add my signature under my emails messages.

Answer (score 3):

You can select *Accounts/Edit account* (crayon icon) at the bottom of the dialog. There is a checkbox to set a signature and a textbox to type your signature in:

[image: how to set signature]

Comment: The box where I have to write signature is out of the screen and I cant scrol to get to it. How can I do?

Comment: You can move any window with Super (Windows) + left-click drag so that the area you want to see becomes visible